Can't open .exe on Windows 11
Windows ignores when I try to open .exe files. A brief 'thinking' symbol appears on the cursor, but when it is gone nothing happens. Running as administrator is also completely ignored, it doesn't even ask if I am sure I want to.
I have tried everything that the internet suggests. I've ran chkdsk and /scannow stuff in the commando prompt, I've done a full system scan, I've edited things in Regedit according to guides on the internet, nothing changes anything.
Not being able to run .exes means I can't install things on the computer. I have 500GB free on the disk, so I should be able to but alas. It is incredibly frustrating, so any help is very welcomed.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Have you rebooted? And yes, that is not the same as turning the computer off and on. Did you press start, shutdown, reboot?

If .exe files are not recognized, that indicates serious Win 11 issues. The safest thing to do is download the ISO from MS and use their tool to make a USB to reinstall Windows, keeping files.

Windows 11 S mode?

Can you launch CMD? if so, type there 'notepad.exe'. Can you open that one?

Right click on an exe file that cannot be opened > properties. Share that screenshot.

What .exe files are you talking about? Did this first occur after downloading or installing something from the internet which you ran? I've edited things in Regedit never a good sign. But, executables are running, clearly, since you have an otherwise functional windows system. Does ctrl+shift+escape bring up the task manager? Does Windows+E bring up file explorer? What if you click start, then type cmd and enter?

If you're run chkdisk and sfc you've actually already run .exe files as these are both exe files. Can you be more specific about WHICH exe files are not working?

Isn't chkdsk an exe file?  How can you run it if you cant run exes?
